# Usage of word "also" instead of "too"

Tags: word-choice, adverbs, word-order, too-also

Is the word "also" used correctly in the sentence "***I also like to live dangerously***"? I know it can be replaced by "too" at the end, but is it OK to use "also"?

The context is that I asked someone if he doesn't sleep at 3 AM, he replayed shortly with "yep" and then I said: "I also like to live dangerously".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely do this. And, like "too", it has two potential uses which are closely tied to the immediately proceeding statement:

> *I also like to live dangerously.*

When proceeded by another person saying something similar, like:

> John: *I like to eat blowfish and drive fast cars.*
>   Mary: *I also like to live dangerously.*

It means that you share the same traits as the person you're talking with. I will say that this use can sound a bit odd and a native speaker (AmE point of view) would probably be more likely to use the "too" form... but that doesn't make it ungrammatical.

When proceeded by another trait you have:

> Mary: *I like to study English and write poetry but don't think I'm not exciting. I also like to live dangerously.*

It means that you have multiple traits. Personally, with this use, I would prefer the "also" form over "too".

That being said, I'm not sure that "staying up until after 3 AM" is "living dangerously". For me, it's just normal.

Comment: Well, it was the real context. And for some people it is really a bad habit going to bed very late. Thank you for the answer! I almost believed that using "also" was wrong, but i guess we (me and my friend, with whom i argued) used "too" more often at school, and it became a habit to use only that format.

Comment: @MarK Well, it really depends on context. It's perfectly grammatical but (as you seem to realize from school) the "too" form is probably slightly more common. I should probably note that in the answer.